# Hamcrest Matchers.equalTo reports false on Gstring to String Comparison

Tags: groovy, spock, hamcrest

I have a list containing params with one value a Gstring. When I compare via Hamcrest I get **String isn't GString** failure even though contents match when compared as Strings

What's the right approach to get Hamcrest to resolve Gstring into string during its comparison?  A workaround is to call `.toString()` on my actual Gstring as I add it to the list but that's not ideal

```
    @Test
    def stackOverflow() {
        given:
        // values
        def v1 = '01'
        def v2 = '02'
        
        // a groovy string containing them
        def param = "${v1}:${v2}"

        // a matcher using a concrete string
        def matcher = Matchers.equalTo("01:02")
        
        when:
        // add actual into a list
        def mylist = [param]

        then:
        // check that actual Gstring matches expected String and fail
        that mylist, Matchers.hasItem(matcher)
    }
```

### Error

```
ondition not satisfied:

that mylist, Matchers.hasItem(matcher)
|    |       |
|    [01:02] class org.hamcrest.Matchers
false

Expected: a collection containing "01:02"
     but: mismatches were: [was <01:02>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `String` instead of `def` when declaring the variable.

```
import static spock.util.matcher.HamcrestSupport.that
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*
import spock.lang.*


class ASpec extends Specification {
    def stackOverflow() {
        given:
        // values
        def v1 = '01'
        def v2 = '02'
        
        // a groovy string containing them
        String param = "${v1}:${v2}"

        // a matcher using a concrete string
        def matcher = equalTo("01:02")
        
        when:
        // add actual into a list
        def mylist = [param]

        then:
        // check that actual Gstring matches expected String and fail
        that mylist, hasItem(matcher)
    }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxlUbtugzAU3f0VV1ElSBWRhDESUjulHaoO6VZ1uDUGrBib2hfSKMq_1w7kQeoB4eN7Hj5-Wlv8jktr2iaLjC2TCmtuhaNoBrXJWyWy6AbqhHXS6CxKkzSaMibrxlgCR0iSg2sM3yYtSZXUSLwSNnkZuJu2CZMJVUh3rFvX5K3nueTxMnUSVahLjzHGFToHz5tGcBC_JHTuIGxkIbmXMxoODPzKRREM-PbdZy6U2cXT4SSsUnZCry7b-Rw6VK1wFyTQuyVkEC2W0RhNT2h6RW9lEHyXptt7byt1CdxoQqnDL1Wivoxu-uMGLdZeb_Jw6JbHlf-mxwkbCw5VQusCA4Ok74rEYDEKd57NQPy0qD5MPFksV4t0Mv2fdlfdVYB5DsjJ80BqMt5KSUdj_X2AvPznKfnXNSrdq_kcfAvhvc-i66GTPqTzz-ffjUR-LgN1DgVKdaPpyb3lDCp0ryTqeLhif6EjO7I_n5zRvQ)

p.s. the `@Test` doesn't belong to Spock and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks Leonard.  That works but I'm hoping for a more general case as I've got all kinds of code (including 3rdparty) that may be using def v String.  Still that's probably a good practice overall to avoid GStrings

Comment: I can't think of a more general solution, you are basically creating a `List<GString>` instead of `List<String>` and Hamcrest matches on that. You could write a custom matcher-wrapper that first transforms `GString` to `String`, but at the end of the day I would question what you are actually trying to test. Of course you could also call `list*.toString()` but that is worse IMHO. Personally I'm ambivalent WRT to the use of `def`, sure it is more succinct, but it can also lead to surprising behavior.

Comment: Thanks folks, I guess I'll need to refactor the code.  That seems the best approach.  BTW, I leav the @test in because it makes the integration with Intellij better or did several years back.  I can probably drop it too

Comment: I don't know of any current problems of `Specification` without `@Test` in IntelliJ.